# How to check if any of the keys are present in any of the values in a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have this dictionary:

```
{
'Bob': ['Paul', 'Mark', 'Carol', 'Leanne', 'Will'],
'Carol': ['Mark', 'Leanne'],
'Farley': ['Paul'],
'Leanne': ['Sarai'],
'Larry': ['Carol', 'Mark', 'Leanne', 'Will'],
'Mark': ['Philip', 'Zach'],
'Paul': ['Zach'],
'Will': ['Leanne', 'Mark'],
'Zach': ['Philip']
}
```

and need to come up with code to check if any of the keys are present in any of the values. I rgwb need to print any key that does not appear in the any of the values. (Should print `Bob`, `Farley`, and `Larry`.) How would I go about doing this — ideally without using `break`?

Comment: If any of the keys are present in any of the values? Or if each key is present in each of the values for the key?

Comment: What does "if any of the keys are present in the values" mean? What is your expected result with the input you described above? Please read [ask].

Comment: @Celisu Stringher If any of the keys are present in any of the values. I believe the end result should print Bob, Farley, and Larry because they are not present in any of the values. Just am not sure how to go about this

Comment: `d.keys() - {v for vs in d.values() for v in vs}`?

Comment: @Chris If any of the keys are present in any of the values. I believe the end result should print Bob, Farley, and Larry because they are not present in any of the values. Just am not sure how to go about this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

returns "the keys that do not appeared in none of the values"

```
import itertools
all_values = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(my_dict.values()))
print(*[x for x in my_dict.keys() if x not in all_values],sep=', ')
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: is it possible to do this without break and return?

Comment: And yes I meant the second one "The keys that do not appear in none of the values"

Comment: Now it prints without {} and ".  I hope I deserved a high-five

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1: Using the set minus operator. See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets.

```
keys = mydict.keys()
for values in mydict.values():
    keys = keys - set(values)
print(keys)
```

Output: {'Bob', 'Larry', 'Farley'}

Solution 2: Using set.union

```
keys = mydict.keys()

## convert list of lists to list of sets
values = [set(x) for x in mydict.values()]
values = set.union(*values)
print(keys - values)
```

Output: {'Bob', 'Larry', 'Farley'}

Comment: This was very helpful. Is there any way to get it to print without {} or '' tho. Like just the names? (I used solution 1)

Comment: You can unpack the keys in the print statement, for example `print(*(keys - values))`. This is equivalent to `print(key1, key2, key3,` etc. Output: `Bob Larry Farley`